# What can be used as substitute to dichloromethane for breaking optical cement bonds?

Tags: solvents, glass

An optics supply company recommends using a dichloromethane solution to break bonds between optical elements joined with its UV-cured optical cement.[1](https://www.norlandprod.com/techrpts/separating.html) The page mentions that dichloromethane-based paint strippers also work. Use of dichloromethane in paint strippers has been phased out in the USA  as of last year. Is there an obvious chemical property that dichloromethane possesses which causes it to break UV cement bonds and if so are there any more readily available hardware store chemicals which could be used as substitute?

Comment: Does not optics deserve pure chemicals ?

Comment: I would think so too but I am sure the manufacturer itself would understand. It is also probably true that such strong solvents also do away with any coatings on the lens elements.

Comment: Acetone or Tri/tetrachloroethylene.  Chloform would be probably the same case as DCM.

Comment: If you follow the supplier instruction is fine. Otherwise, optical element it is a vague term. There are optical elements which can be washed in organic solvents and other which will be ruined. In your case is probably lenses (or anyway metal, or inorganic glasses) and you should do what they said. I do not think that chlorinated solvents are banned for every use. Try also acetone anyway, as Poutnik said.

Comment: Write them an email asking for a non-chlorinated alternative? They know about the problem.

Comment: Chlorinated solvents or acetone are usually ok. AR coatings are normally inorganic materials such as MgF2 so should be ok with solvent. The solvent may leave residue on the lens/mirror if not pure, clean this off with iso propyl alcohol, use a proper lens tissue not any old tissue as these will scratch at microscopic level. Drag tissue across surface, do not 'scrub'.

Comment: If acetone doesn't work so well, cyclohexane or petrol ether / benzine are the next guess.

Comment: Just because dichloromethane has been phased out in paint stripper (it was never used in paint *thinner* and I'm surprised it has been phased out) doesn't mean you can't get the pure chemical. It is fairly safe in small amounts and probably safer than alternatives like acetone.

Comment: @matt_black I think the way that comment is written could cause a false sense of security. DCM is a volatile, permeable carcinogen. It can be used safely, but only if its dangers are respected.

Comment: @electronpusher dCM is not a carcinogen in people. It was suspected to be a human carcinogen (because its congener chloroform clearly is) and widely tested. But isn't. The major hazard of DCM is from displacement of air in confined spaces leading to suffocation (plenty of accidents from that but you need a large amount of DCM). Toxicity is not a major hazard for users of small amounts who treat it with caution.

Comment: @matt_black It is also suspected to be a human carcinogen because it has shown to be carcinogenic in mice, rats and hamsters. Human data is insufficient for a full conclusion, but the current recommendation is to classify DCM as a suspected human carcinogen (category 2). I would be interested to see what evidence informs your claim that DCM is not carcinogenic in humans (are you so sure there's enough data for such a bold claim of safety?) https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33387565/

Comment: @electronpusher The link between animal studies and human carcinogenicity is suspect because some of the key metabolic pathways in rodents are not found in people. actual human epidemiology studies are weak and inconsistent with no clear conclusions. I can't claim DCM certainly *isn't* a problem (but I can't claim that for most chemicals either). If it were a notable problem the results from human exposure studies would be stronger and clearer than they are.

Answer (score 1):

According to an email i got back from Norland, "It will work if the paint stripper has a chlorinated ketone in it"

Comment: Careful here most simple chlorinated ketones are good lachrymators aka tear gas.